# Perl - to create and sort hash to produce a sorted output

Tags: sorting, perl, hash

So I have this script that scrape data to a website, its getting and downloading a CSV and its process the CSV row by row and converts it into TSV, once that finished the TSV file will be converted into a HTML file. I'm done the rest of that but the output that I'm getting is some what messed up, the script goes to different table pages on the source site and downloads a dynamically generated CSV file; that CSV file is then turned into a TSV file that we then turn into HTML.  The CSV file seems to be sorted by the first column for each row that is returned but not based on any of the other columns in the same row.  Therefore what is happening is that entries with the same first column values can be jumbled up from one download to the next download of the same file.

A visual representation of only sorting by the first column this follows with numbers representing column data:

1st Download:
1-1
1-2
1-3
2-1
2-2
2-3
3-1
3-2
3-3

2nd Download:
1-1
1-3
1-2
2-2
2-1
2-3
3-3
3-2
3-1

So what I have in mind is the process will be like this, download the CSV file from the source and then perform a sort on the lines in that CSV file to normalize them for comparison to one another before writing the TSV or HTML files.  This should allow for accurate comparison for updated data files. but I didn't know how to do this my logic is like this
[image]

So I will put the function between the 1. and 2. before it process the CSV file into TSV File I want the content of the CSV is already sorted.

So my script is looking like this

```
 my $download_dir_link ="C:/Users/jabella/Downloads";
unlink("$download_dir_link/Product Classification List.csv");

            #CHECK IF CSV FILE DOWNLOAD IS FINISHED
            my $complete_download_flag = 0;
            
            while($complete_download_flag == 0)
            {
                my @download_directory = read_dir($download_dir_link);
                foreach my $downloaded_file (@download_directory)
                {
                    if($downloaded_file =~ /\QProduct Classification List.csv\E/sgi)
                    {
                        $complete_download_flag = 1;
                    }
                }
                sleep(5);
            }
            #SORTED CONTENTS OF CSV BEFORE CONVERSION
            print "sORTING csv content...\n";
            
            #CONVERT CSV TO TSV
            print "Converting csv to tsv...\n";
            my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1 });
            my $tsv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, sep_char => "\t", eol => "\n"});
            
            open my $infh,  "<:encoding(utf8)", "$download_dir_link/Product Classification List.csv";
            open my $outfh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "Product Classification List.tsv";
            
            while (my $row = $csv->getline ($infh)) 
            {
                $tsv->print ($outfh, $row);
            }
            close($infh);
            close($outfh);
            
            my $tsv_content = "";
            open(my $fh, '<', "Product Classification List.tsv");
            while (<$fh>) 
            {
                $tsv_content = $tsv_content.$_;
            }
            close($fh);
            print "Conversion complete! cleaning tsv content...\n";
            #CLEAN TSV CONTENT
            

            $tsv_content =~ s/(.*?)\t"(.*?)"\t"(.*?)"\t"(.*?)"\t(.*?)\t"(.*?)"\t(.*)/<tr><th>$1<\/th><th>$2<\/th><th>$3<\/th><th>$4<\/th><th>$5<\/th><th>$6<\/th><th>$7<\/th><\/tr>/gi;
            $tsv_content =~ s/"?(.*?)"?\t"?(.*?)"?\t"?(.*?)"?\t"?(.*?)"?\t"?(.*?)"?\t"?(.*?)"?\t"?(.*?)"?\n/<tr><td>$1<\/td><td>$2<\/td><td>$3<\/td><td>$4<\/td><td>$5<\/td><td>$6<\/td><td>$7<\/td><\/tr>\n/gi;
            $tsv_content =~ s/\"{2}/\"/sgi;
            $tsv_content =~ s/(<\/tr>)\n?"/$1/sgi;
            $tsv_content =~ s/\s{2,}/ /sgi;
            $tsv_content =~ s/.*?(<tr>)/$1/si;
            $tsv_content = "<table>\n$tsv_content</table>";
            
            $classification =~ s/_//sgi;
            
            if(exists $existing_index_hash{$doc_uid."_pind.html"})
            {
                if($existing_index_hash{$doc_uid."_pind.html"} ne $tsv_content)
                {
                    $changed_flag = "1";
                    $updated_files = $updated_files."-$classification\n";
                    print "Updated: $classification\n";
```

Hope someone here can help me on this thank you

Comment: Most of the code you posted is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Also, do you really need a hash? If you want to keep the original order, use an array.

Comment: what i'm showing is the fucntion that I made, What i'm lacking now is the function that will sorted the content of the CSV files into ascending before the converstion of the CSV into TSV file

Comment: I just think of that, I really don't know how to create that function. :( so any help will do

Comment: Without a sample CSV, I can't run your code to play with it.

Comment: Here is the CSV file you can download it here https://www4.palmettogba.com/pdac_dmecs/searchProductClassificationResults.do?manufacturer=&codeDecision=&productName=&modelNumber=&classification=Surgical+Dressings

Comment: As you notice in there , its dynamically sorted by first column only .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple script that loads a CSV file specified as an argument and outputs it sorted by the first two columns.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = 'Text::CSV_XS'->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1});

open my $in, '<', shift or die $!;
my @rows;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($in)) {
    push @rows, $row;
}

# Here the sorting happens. Compare the first column,
# if the values are the same, compare the second column.
@rows = sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] || $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] } @rows;

$csv->say(*STDOUT, $_) for @rows;
```

You can use the following to sort by all columns (but it compares the values as strings, it doesn't work for numbers):

```perl
sub by_all {
    my ($n, $A, $B) = @_;
    $A->[$n] cmp $B->[$n]
        || $n < $#$A && by_all($n + 1, $A, $B)
}

sort { by_all(0, $a, $b) } @rows;
```

To make it work for numbers, too, you can let Perl guess what is a number:

```perl
use Scalar::Util qw{ looks_like_number };

sub by_all {
    my ($n, $A, $B) = @_;
    (looks_like_number($A->[$n])
        ? $A->[$n] <=> $B->[$n]
        : $A->[$n] cmp $B->[$n]
    ) || $n < $#$A && by_all($n + 1, $A, $B)
}
```

Comment: Hello Choroba , can you please show how can put this on my script ? I'm really new to Perl programming I just recently begin my study about this, would you kind enough to show how can I put it on my script ? I noted on my script where to put this function **#I WANT TO PUT THE FUNCTION RIGHT HERE** on my script. Thank you very much .

Comment: I can't run your script, e.g. `read_dir` is not declared anywhere. Therefore, I can't test how to make it work. On the other hand, you can run my script as is and it will work.

Comment: I put my directory on the script above , I really don't how can I incorporate the one make into my script, I really want to put the function yuo made just before the conversion form CSV into TSV.

Comment: The point is, you don't read the CSV line by line and print it. You read it into an array, sort the array, then print the sorted array into the output TSV.

Comment: is there to write it into file ? I mean the sorted array will be stored into a another CSV file and that CSV file is the new file to be converted into TSV file

Comment: My example outputs to `*STDOUT`, but you can use `$outfh` instead.

Comment: hello choroba, I tested your script but it seems that its not sorted as ascending ,the data is still not arranged into ascending format. as you notices the CSV file that I sent to you it is not arranged as ascending ,The CSV file seems to be sorted by the first column for each row that is returned but not based on any of the other columns in the same row. Therefore what is happening is that entries with the same first column values can be jumbled up. Can you please help me on this if you can? Thank you

Comment: Can you please show 2 lines that aren't sorted as expected by my code? It seems to work for me.

Comment: Here is the sample data, It is the same data from the CSV file that I sent to you. this is arranged into ascending format https://onlinegdb.com/-jxHJ_HAu it already a HTML file but as you notices here all row and all of its column is arranged into ascending manner, the script that you sent me is outputing a ascending format for the 1st and 2nd column only.

Comment: Yes, my code sorts by first two columns. If you want more, just add `|| $a->[2] cmp $a->[2]` etc.

Comment: See the update for a solution to sort (alphabetically) for all the columns regardless of their number.

Comment: You said that it compares the values as strings, it doesn't work for numbers, so the column with numbers will not be sort on ascending format ?

Comment: They will be sorted alphabetically, i.e. `"10" lt "2"`. You need to use `<=>` instead of `cmp` if you want numeric comparison, but you need to know when to use what.

Comment: Check the update for an example how to do it.

Comment: ohh I get it , I'll try this one choroba, can you please show how to write it into another CSV? I'm really really confuse on how to do that, my bad its really my first time programming on perl and studying writing and reading file.

Comment: As written 17 hours ago, just replace `*STDOUT` with `$outfh`.

Comment: I tried that but i'm getting some error. https://onlinegdb.com/x6lDHQzru

Comment: What error? I don't see any in the IDE, and when I run it, it complains about missing Selenium::Chrome which is totally unrelated to the issue. Also, you're missing `@rows = ` before [sort](https://perldoc.pl/sort). Sort doesn't sort an array in place, it returns a sorted list.

Comment: Also, you removed opening of `$outfh`. This can't work.

Comment: Can you show me on how you do it ? can you combined all of the script into 1 single file? really sorry I really struggles on this.

Comment: I can explain you things, I can help you learn stuff. But I'm not going to give you a code for free - that's not how StackOverflow works.